# find all the records belongs to particular Id are decommissioned

Tags: r

I need to find the records which are decommissioned based on date.

below is the example data frame:

input date: 2020-08-01(YYYY-MM-DD)

```
df <- data.frame(cel = c("cel12", "cel34", "cel05", "cel98", "cel67", 
                         "cel35", "cel05", "cel45", "cel12","cel99","cel45"), 
                 sect = c("sect56", "sect56", "sect56", "sect78", "sect78", 
                        "sect60", "sect51", "sect51", 
                          "sect98", "sect98", "sect98"), 
                 site = c("site14","site14", "site08", "site08", "site08", 
                        "site89", "site89", "site08", "site24",
                          "site24", "site36"),
                 decomdate = c(as.Date("2020-02-01"),as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), as.Date("2020-05-01"), NA, NA, as.Date("2020-12-01"), as.Date("2020-07-01"), as.Date("2020-06-01"), NA, NA))
```

if all the 'cel' in particular 'sect' belongs to particular 'site' are decommissioned(i.e decomdate < inputdate) then that 'sect' is decommissioned.

Expected Output: sect column with decommissioned sects

```
   sect
   sect56
   sect51
```

Comment: what have you tried, and what isn't working? You can use `<` and `>` operators to filter date objects.

Comment: In your example all decomdates are smaller than input date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `sect` we can check if `all` the `decomdate` is less than `input` date.

```
library(dplyr)
input <- as.Date('2020-08-01')

df %>%  group_by(sect) %>% filter(all(input > decomdate))

#  cel   sect   decomdate 
#  <chr> <chr>  <date>    
#1 cel12 sect56 1964-06-20
#2 cel34 sect56 1964-06-19
#3 cel05 sect56 1964-06-17
#4 cel05 sect51 1964-06-17
#5 cel45 sect51 1964-06-15
```

To get only `sect` back we can use `distinct` :

```
df %>% group_by(sect) %>% filter(all(input > decomdate)) %>% distinct(sect)

#  sect  
#  <chr> 
#1 sect56
#2 sect51
```

---

This can also be done using base R with `subset` and `ave` :

```
unique(subset(df, ave(input > decomdate, sect, FUN = all), select = sect))
```

Comment: It's supposed to be `decomdate > input`. Also the format of the input date is DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: Ok..this is weird. When I use `dput` provided by OP it gives me dates with 1964 as year, also it is of class `Date` but I can see in the question the date is in 2020. Does that happen with you?

Comment: whoah...yes it does. dput was edited by another user into the question but still, this does not explain the 1964s

Comment: ohh..wait I get it. That is because OP uses `01-02-2020` as a number  and not as string `"01-02-2020"`.

Comment: ahhh...indeed. Good eye!

Comment: I have updated my question,  I need to consider one more column called 'site'.  and need to find 'sect' belongs to particular 'site' is decommissioned or not.('sect' is decommissioned when all its 'cel' decomdate is less than input date for particular 'site'). In the example I have given,  the sect56 belongs to site14 is decommissioned because all its cel decommisioned, but sect56 belongs to site08 is not decommisioned. I need decommissioned sect56 which is belogs to site14.

Comment: @Hmm I think it should give you the expected output if you add `site` in `group_by` like `df %>% group_by(sect, site) %>%  filter(all(input > decomdate)) %>% ungroup %>% distinct(sect)`

Comment: sorry, I got the expected output. Thank you

Comment: I want to compare this result combination in other data frame (i.e sect and site combination in another data frame). I have written like below, I feel its not robust. is there any alternative for this.

          `paste0(sect, site) %in% paste0(decommissioned_sectors$sect, 
                                                                           decommissioned_sectors$site))`

Comment: Please don't extend the question in comments. If you have more questions ask it as a new question.